# Problem with connecting an ESP32 with a DSLR camera

Tags: arduino, pcb, esp32

I have a problem connecting a microcontroller and DSLR.
First of all, the code and the hardware was tested on a Nikon D5600 and everything worked.

20 days later, it was tested on a Nikon D5500 and it didn't work. I didn't test it, but I was present there and it worked, so I need to figure it out why is not working for me.

I am using an ESP32 connected via the shutter release cable so I can remotely take a shot. I am attaching schematics and some photos.

I need your help.

Here are some of my conclusions:

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page on shutter release cables,](https://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/) there are only three pins involved in the shutter release of the Nikon D5500.

[image]

Double check which wire is connected to which pin using an ohmmeter, then do a simple test. Connect the shutter wire directly to the ground wire.  The camera should make a picture.

If the camera doesn't make a picture then there's either something wrong with it or there's some [setting in the camera that you need to change.](https://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/ETOYI00bfdW602XchPU57r5bLc70/D5500RM_(En)03.pdf)

Once you can get the camera to make a photo just by shorting the wires, you can try your circuit and software again.

The connections to the optocoupler look OK.  I don't see any obvious mistake, but that's not to say that the circuit you built is exactly like the diagram.

Comment: Thank you! You mean I just take ground wire and shutter wire and touch them together ?

Comment: Yep.  That's all it takes to try it out.

Comment: that doesn't work. But when I just plug in a cable into audio jack it fires a shot